# Stop Framer Motion's useScroll from affecting two instances of the same component simultaneously

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I'm creating a sticky container with a nested element that animates a component's x position based on the users scroll position with Framer Motion.

I put it all together and thought it was working until I rendered out two instances of the same component. Both are currently animating at the same time but I want them to behave independently and only start their respective animation when they're visible in the viewport.

I believe my issue is down to how I've set up useScroll as I believe it's tracking the entire page rather than the motion component within it's container. I'm reading through the docs on Framer Motion and there are two options within useScroll that I've been toying with to try and get it to work `target` and `container`.

Below is a stripped down version demonstrating the useRef, useScroll, and the HTML:

```
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const { scrollY } = useScroll({ target: ref });
```

```
    <section className="container" ref={ref}>
      <div className="galleryContainer">
        <div>
          <motion.div
            className="scrollingContainer"
            style={{ x: xPercent }}
            transition={{ type: "inertia", velocity: 50 }}
          >
            test
          </motion.div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

The FM docs state that "To track the scroll position of a scrollable element, instead of that of the page, we can pass a ref to both useScroll's `container` option and the element." but my parent container is not a scrollable element and when I set `container: ref` rather than `target: ref` the animation stops working altogether, I'm unsure of where to go from here.

I've set up a Code Sandbox to demonstrate the current behaviour:

https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-parallax-forked-jv8w4i?file=/src/App.tsx

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.